# Eclipse. Set minimum JDK version for JAR library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I've developed a java jar-library and simple java program for test this library. It works on my machine with JDK 7, but doesn't work on machines with oldest JRE. How can I make it run with minimum JRE it's required?

JAR library generated using Eclipse: File/Export/Jar.

Comment: If the classes inside your jar library use some features of JDK 7 then it cannot be used by an application which uses older version of JRE.

Comment: Change the compiler version from project properties before export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project > properties > Java Compiler and set the compiler compliance settings for this project.  Try setting this to this earlier JRE version and make changes based on warnings / errors that manifest.

Answer (score 2):

maybe your application should check the jre version and print a message to the user?

get java version like this:

```
String st = System.getProperty("java.version");
```

Comment: In a META-INF/MANIFEST Main-Class compiler with an old JDK version. This could then call the original main class.

Comment: If the class containing this code is compiled with Java 7 it will not be able to run to do the check.